# Access/Download server files, not in site root, with PHP

Tags: php, file-get-contents

Usually I save documents (images, mpegs, excel, word docs, etc...) for my friends or family on my website's root, inside a directory called /files/  or something similar.  Nothing too uncommon.

But, I have been playing with user session control, and allowing users to upload files to the dedicated /files/ directory. (the file names are saved in a db, with that user's ID)

But, that means other people could try to guess and locate other people's files.
I do randomize the file names, upon upload.  And I stop the apache from displaying the /files/ directory content.

However, I'd like to start saving the files outside of the website's root.  This way it can't be accessible via the browser.

I don't have any code to show, but I didn't want to even start on this endeavor if it's not able to be accomplished.  I did find this snippet that shows how to display an image, from outside your website root:

Maybe I can use this for any file type, but has anyone heard of a better way to allow users (logged in) to access their files from online, but not letting other users has similar access?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The PHP manual gives good insight on how to achieve this with an example on the [`readfile` function's page](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.readfile.php):

```
<?php
$file = 'monkey.gif';

if (file_exists($file)) {
    header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
    header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.basename($file));
    header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
    header('Expires: 0');
    header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
    header('Pragma: public');
    header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));
    ob_clean();
    flush();
    readfile($file);
    exit;
}
?>
```

This forces any file to be downloadable by setting the content-disposition and content-type headers.  That's pretty much the way this sort of thing is usually done, `file_get_contents` will allow you to do the same thing too.