# How do I access files placed outside of the site root?

Tags: php, mysql, apache

I have fried my brain all day on this. Researching SO until my eyes are bleary...I need to know: How do I access files placed outside the site root?

Background: Apache 2.0 dedicated server running Linux.

Code: PHP and MySQL

Reason: I want the files to be secured against typing in the file path and filename into a browser.

This can't be that difficult...but my splitting head says otherwise. Any help would be absolutely appreciated.

Comment: Your question would benefit from some clarification. You've said you're using LAMP; are you trying to access these files from *Apache* or *PHP code*? If the latter (which seems most likely), is *that* code inside the site root?

Comment: If it's a php file accessing another php file (like an index file loading application files), you can specify a relative or absolute path, or you can add your application folder to php's path environment. That will slow other things down, though.

Comment: I may be wrong here.. but if you use aliases as suggested in some of the links provided, I'm fairly sure you'd still have the same issue with people being able to type the URL in.  Using .htaccess you can prevent anything apart from requests from your own pages display images (images served any other means will result in 403 errors) - http://corz.org/serv/tricks/htaccess.php; you could also use a PHP script to serve the files.  The PHP could then be used to determine how download requests are handled, and also means img src are not just flat *.jpg links

Comment: @pjmorse I want to access the files with PHP from within the site root, yes. My apology for the lack of clarification, but after a day of fruitless searching and experimenting, my brain is shot.

Comment: There has got to be a way to keep the files in their folders safe from direct downloading through a browser. If not, every pay site on the interner would be out of business.

Comment: @ChrisW Good to know. Actually, I am serving up images to display on the site in galleries and videos to download for the members.

Comment: OK. So what you want is a way to, in PHP, open a file outside the site root, and return that file to the browser. Have you tried `file_get_contents()` providing a root URL as the argument?

Comment: @pjmorse Actually, no, but thank you for the suggestion. I will try that now. Thank you!

Comment: @pjmorse forgot to ask...is this technique ok for video files?

Comment: @wordman just posted a proper answer. I'm not experienced with this myself, but `file_get_contents()` should let you push contents of any file out to a user. You could probably push a stream with different code than that used in the example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have a look at the [answers to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2581714/306084), which seem to be doing more or less the same thing.

A quick summary: [`readfile()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.readfile.php) or [`file_get_contents()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php) are what you're after. This example comes from the `readfile()` page:

```
<?php
$file = 'monkey.gif';

if (file_exists($file)) {
    header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
    header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.basename($file));
    header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
    header('Expires: 0');
    header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
    header('Pragma: public');
    header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));
    ob_clean();
    flush();
    readfile($file);
    exit;
}
?>
```

I don't recommend allowing the `$file` variable to be set using user input! Think about where the filenames are coming from before arbitrarily returning files in the response.

Comment: I know this is a long time since I posted this question, but the above code...how does it know it's looking outside the site's root folder? I want to understand better how this works.

Comment: Just feed it a root URL (e.g. `/home/me/files/monkey.gif` instead of just `monkey.gif`).

Comment: And that worked like a charm! Now to integrate that into the site. My apologies for getting back to this so late, but I was pulled off of this project until today.

Comment: Useful is putting it mildly. You're a lifesaver. Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

are you trying to access files outside of site root? Then you can look at this [link in stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5570085/accessing-files-outside-the-document-root-with-apache).
And this is the [official doc](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/urlmapping.html#outside) in Apache.

Otherwise you don't have to do special handling to prevent others from accessing files outside site root.

Comment: Actually, I read that post here on SO several times today. I read another where the use of ailiases could be avoided, hence my total confusion about this. I need clearer information than what I'm reading online. Every question seems to be answered in a way that only makes sense to people who already know how to do this which leaves me no further ahead.